# How to make a set of sets in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I get this set of sets?

```
{{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}}
```

Answer (score 0):

`set` aren't hashable so you can't put `set` inside a `set`.  However, you *can* make a `set` of `frozenset`...

```
{frozenset([1]), frozenset([2])}
```